# The ViewData item that has the key 'GenderID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The error occurs when i tried to Submit/Post the data... could someone please help i tried every post but they are not helping me. I am new to mvc... any help will be granted
here is my code...

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   UserProfileCreateViewModel model = new UserProfileCreateViewModel();
   model.Gender = _GenderRepository.GetAll()
       .Select(x => new SelectListItem
       {
           Value = x.ID.ToString(),
           Text = x.DESCRIPTION
       });
   return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UserProfileCreateViewModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      UserProfile user = new UserProfile();
      user.GENDER_ID = model.GenderID;
      _UserProfileRepository.Add(user);
      _UserProfileRepository.Save();
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
   }
   return View(model);
}
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GenderID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GenderID, Model.Gender, "Select from List", new { @class = "form-control" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GenderID, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
</div>
```

Model

```
public class UserProfileCreateViewModel
{
   [Required(ErrorMessage="{0} is required")]
    [Display(Name="Gender")]
    public int GenderID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Gender { get; set; }
}
```

> InvalidOperationException: The ViewData item that has the key 'GenderID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

Here i have tried this....
// POST: /UserProfile/Create/

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(UserProfileCreateViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            UserProfile user = new UserProfile();

            user.GENDER_ID = model.GenderID;

            _UserProfileRepository.Add(user);
            _UserProfileRepository.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        model.Gender = _GenderRepository.GetAll().Select(x =>
                                                    new SelectListItem
                                                    {
                                                        Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                                                        Text = x.DESCRIPTION
                                                    });
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Add your stacktrace or at least point out where the exception is being raised.

Comment: Exception is raised at View At this line                                                         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GenderID, Model.Gender, "Select from List", new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're passing the wrong parameters to the `DropDownListFor` function. I think you should be creating a new SelectList somewhere in there...

Comment: I have created the dropdownlist in the same way in another project its working fine there but not working here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the value of `Model.Gender` is `null` (and as a result the `DropDownListFor()` method expects that the first parameter is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

In your case, when you submit the form and `ModelState` is invalid, you return the view and have not assigned a value to `Model.Gender` (hence it is `null` and the excption is thrown.

Ensure that you re-assign the value of `Model.Gender` in the POST method (just as you did in the GET method) before you return the view.

Comment: Of course it works. Edit your question to add the new code you tried so I can correct it.

Comment: I have rolled back your changes (you cannot change the original question - the answer and comments then make no sense). Instead add the new code you have tried to the end of your question.

Comment: The revised code you have shown will work perfectly fine (it appears to be the identical code that you used to set the value in the GET method). So if its not, then there is something else you have done which is setting the value of `Model.Gender` to `null`. I suggest you add a `<div>@Model.Gender.ToString()</div>` in you view and put a breakpoint on it and see if your getting a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: its not giving NullReferenceException

Comment: Then your revised code works fine! The only way that that particular error can be shown is if the value of `Model.Gender` is `null` (and if you want a link to the source code so your can step through it and prove it, then let me know)

Comment: i debug the code. when i post data it changes the value of Gender ID but The value of Gender is still null.

Comment: What do you mean its `null`? The value of `model.Gender` will always be null when you submit the form back to the controller (you don't generate an input for each property of each `SelctListItem` in the view - and it would be nonsense to do so). That is why you have to reassign it (as per my answer) before you return the view.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get it

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem between the "Gender":

```
[Display(Name="Gender")]
public int GenderID { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Gender { get; set; }
```

If I remember well, MVC attempts to map the fields automatically. Try renaming the `(Name="Gender")` in `(Name="GenderID")` or `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Gender` in `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GenderEnumeration`